# Can I do parallel processing without loop or combining?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, dplyr

I need a parallel processing for long task to save my time and AWS cost.
I've searched about parallel processing using 'foreach' and 'doParallel' packages.
But I wonder if there is an way to do without combining or loop.

For example, I want to execute the task like code below with parallel processing.

```
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by=c("user_id", "first_order"=="order_number")) %>% 
    mutate(col3=col2-col1)
```

(It is very shortened code for example.)

I tried to convert my code to function using index i of data to use foreach loop, 
but converting lower the execution speed down significantly.

Is there an way to do my task with parallel or another faster way?

Comment: If you use **dplyr** there exists [**multidplyr**](https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/blob/master/vignettes/multidplyr.md) but I don't think it works really well at the moment. You can also try to use **data.table** instead of dplyr, which should be faster. Finally, you should profile your code to see if there is one operation that takes the most of the whole execution time and try to parallelize only this one.

Comment: @F.Privé Thank you for the information! I know the data.table but i'm not good at it yet. I'll study more data.table and multidplyr. Thank you again!